# Using Table Recursively

Tags: list-manipulation, recursion

I wonder if it's possible to create a list with `Table` from entries of the list itself. That is, as I'm creating the list, I append a new element as a function of previously added elements, in a "recursive" way.

For example, the following code does what I mean

```
lt = {1};
For[i = 2, i <= 5, i++, lt = Append[lt, lt[[i - 1]] + 1]];
lt
```

giving `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`. I wonder if the same can be achieved with `Table`. I naively tried

```
lt = {1};
lt = Table[lt[[i - 1]] + 1, {i, 2, 5}]
```

which unsurprisingly doesn't work. Maybe there is an alternative to this that avoids using `For` and `Append`. I've heard of `RecurrenceTable`, but I'm not entirely sure how it works.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `NestList`, or `NestWhileList` in case when you need access to more than one previous element. In your case, it would be `NestList[# + 1 &, 1, 4]`. You can also use simple `Nest` even when you need access to previous results, by collecting them in a (sub)list. Here is for example a way to compute Fibonacci numbers: `NestList[{Last@ #, Total[#]} &, {1, 1}, 10][[All, 1]]`. Also, `Nest` auto-compiles, so this method can be reasonably fast if the nesting function is compilable

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In my opinion, `NestList` is the most direct answer to the question in the OP, i.e. to "create a list from entries of the list itself", as [Leonid suggested](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/212610/using-table-recursively#comment544485_212610) as well. The simple example in the OP then becomes:

```
NestList[# + 1 &, 1, 4]
```

> `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`

`NestWhileList` allows a function to run until a certain condition is met, in those cases in which the number of iterations is not known *a priori*:

```
NestWhileList[# + 2 &, 1, # < 20 &]
```

> `{1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21}`

I mention this example specifically because it highlights a behavior that trips me up from time to time: the generated item that finally falsified the condition **is included in the results**. This is the first point in the [Details section of the docs for this function](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestWhileList.html). Of course `Most@NestWhileList[...]` can be used to remove that last item, if needed.

The tutorial on [Applying Functions Repeatedly](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ApplyingFunctionsRepeatedly.html) might be of interest as well.

Answer (score 7):

Use [`RecurrenceTable`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RecurrenceTable.html) or [`RSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RSolve.html)

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Clear[lt]

RecurrenceTable[{lt[n + 1] == lt[n] + 1, lt[1] == 1}, lt, {n, 1, 5}]

(* {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} *)
```

Or find a general term of the table

```
sol = RSolve[{lt[n + 1] == lt[n] + 1, lt[1] == 1}, lt, n][[1]]

(* {lt -> Function[{n}, n]} *)
```

Verifying that the solution satisfies the equations

```
{lt[n + 1] == lt[n] + 1, lt[1] == 1} /. sol

(* {True, True} *)
```

Generating a table from the general solution

```
lt /@ Range[5] /. sol

(* {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} *)
```